# Authentication with JWT between multiple microservices

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices

I have an application with

1. Front end Angular Component
2. Login service - validates username and password and provides JWT token(Service A)
3. Book Tickets service - Save/retrieve data about ticket bookings

Note:

> Login and Booking service has its own DB.

> Not using an API gateway

Flow:

> Front End <-> /authenticate(ServiceA) <-> validate creds on login DB and return JWT token.

After this call, I would require the Book Tickets service to be authenticated by passing the JWT that was created in the previous step. But how can I do this without connecting the LoginDB to the Book Tickets Service?

What I was hoping to do (But unsure if they are good practices) :

1. Create an endpoint in LoginService "/isValidUser" and call this endpoint from Book Tickets service every time.
2. Route all Book tickets service endpoint through Login service so JWT is validated and the request is forwarded.
3. Let Book Ticket Service access the Login DB and implement JWT validation in this service itself.

Really appreciate you suggestions.

Comment: Oftentimes / normally a JWT is self contained and is valid as long as it is properly signed, for the right aud, not expired, etc. at that point there is no need to ask the login service for its validity other than maybe retrieve the public key for the signature check. But that last part can be done once during application startup or every couple of hours or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

In Microservices architecture mostly one service talk to another service using standard interface or say web api.

In your case, you are right that you need LoginService and it has following responsibilities.

- Validate Crendential ( Username , Password) and return JWT Token.

  - Now this token will be used by Frontend to communicate with Backend or other services like Book Ticket Service etc.
- IsTokenValid

Now Book Ticket Service has following responsibility.

- Booking Ticket.

Possible flow of Booking Ticket is like.

1. /bookingservice/BookTicket ( with all data)

   - Also JWT Token pass in header.
2. BookTicket service will receive request and it also extract token from header.
3. It will pass token to Login Service to validate that token is valid or not.
4. If it is valid then you can perform book ticket.

If you allow Book Ticket Service to access Db of Login Service, overall purpose of Microservices will not be there. Because as soon as there is some change in Login Service DB, you also have to change Book Ticket Service.

- For small project like once you are creating and then you are not going to change for long time then it may be ok but in that Microservices purpose is not there.